# Comparing a Date Range to a set of Date Ranges SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, t-sql, datetime

Ok, so this particular use case is giving me quite a bit of headache.

What i am trying to do is figure out if any StartDate and EndDates in a set is overlapping with a set of Start and EndDates, if they are, the overlapping rows must be returned.

**DateRange Table** -- contains all DateRanges

```
DateRangeId StartDate                   EndDate                     CustomerJobQuery_Id WorkWish_Id
----------- --------------------------- --------------------------- ------------------- -----------
1           2014-03-31 00:00:00.0000000 2014-08-18 00:00:00.0000000 NULL                1
2           2014-08-25 00:00:00.0000000 2014-09-15 00:00:00.0000000 NULL                1
3           2013-08-24 00:00:00.0000000 2014-09-25 00:00:00.0000000 1                   NULL
```

**Workwish Table**

```
Id          Candidate_Id
----------- ------------
1           5
```

**CustomerJobQuery Table**

```
Id          Customer_CustomerId
----------- -------------------
1           2
```

this is my DateRange table.. what my StoredProcedure accepts is a CandidateId; i wish to find the Candidate Id's WorkWishes , Match the DateRanges of the WorkWish with ALL of the CustomerJobQuery DateRanges and return the CustomerJobQueries that had overlapping dates.

I figured out how to do the check if a specific DateRange overlaps with another DateRange.. but i am stumped as to how to do this comparison on a set.

Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this query:

```
SELECT c.*
  FROM CustomerJobQuery c
  WHERE EXISTS ( 
    SELECT 1
     FROM Workwish w
     INNER JOIN DateRange d1 ON d1.CustomerJobQuery_Id = c.Id
     INNER JOIN DateRange d2 ON d2.WorkWish_Id = w.Id
     WHERE w.Candidate_Id = 5 -- CandidateId in procedure
      -- overlap check:
      AND d1.StartDate <= d2.EndDate
      AND d2.StartDate <= d1.EndDate
  )
```

Test it here (SQL Fiddle): http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/10253/3